# Metaplex Create NFT Error: Transfer: `from` must not carry data

Tags: nft, metaplex-js, signature, systemprogram

I'm trying to combine the instructions from the metaplex create nft builder with a sol transfer instruction. I got this far:

```
    let useNewMint = Keypair.generate();
    let localMeta = Metaplex.make(connection)
        .use(keypairIdentity(useNewMint))    
    let payer = // client pubkey

    let createNFT = await localMeta.nfts().builders().create({
        uri: "",
        name: `Helix Test Airdrop`,
        useNewMint,
    });


    transaction = createNFT.toTransaction({
        blockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
    });

    // transfer sol to helix wallet
    transaction.add(SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: payer,
        toPubkey: vaultWallet,
        lamports: LAMPORTS_PER_SOL * 0.1,
    }));

    transaction.feePayer = payer;

    transaction.partialSign(useNewMint);

    await signTransaction(transaction);

    const signature = await connection.sendRawTransaction(transaction.serialize(), { skipPreflight: true });

    console.log(`✅ Success: ${signature}`);
```

Here is an example transaction that failed with the error:
https://solscan.io/tx/3M2T7shNEVWB7zVFhw1fHbrcmGLSkyihyQPb4XoB3QSMrqWbYgrZ49ize2a7YHPqJXMugTdn8KnFRj2TVcvnmhXB?cluster=devnet

Error shown on solscan:

```
#1 System Program instruction
   > Transfer: `from` must not carry data
   > Program returned error: invalid program argument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error means that the during the SOL transfer, the `from` pubkey, which is `payer`, is actually a data account, and not a simple SOL wallet. Maybe it's actually a token account?

It looks like something happened to `payer` during the transaction to create an account on that address, which is why the transfer afterwards is failing.